# Get entity proxy in Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm, relationship, proxy-classes

I have an entity *Dog* with OneToOne relation to *Collar*.

Say I create a new *Dog* entity and I have the *Collar* id I want to relate to it. Not the *Collar* object itself, **only it's id number**.

```
$collar = 12;
$dog = new Dog();
$dog->setCollar(?);
```

Do I need to actually **fetch** the *Collar* object from the DB, only to set it's id (which is already given), or is there a way to create a proxy *Collar* object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there actually is

You can use your entity manager to get a Proxy Reference instead of an actual Entity which just gives you a proxy object representing the Entity without actually fetching it from the database.

Check the code below for an example

```
$collarId = 12;

// First param is the Entity classname, second is the Entity id
$collar = $entityManager->getReference('Collar', $collarId); 

$dog = new Dog();
$dog->setCollar($colar);

$entityManager->persist($dog);
$entityManager->flush();
```